No entiendo por qué la variable de sesión no se mantiene
Con mis limitados conocimientos de php y mysql hice este login, quería que la $_SESSION['reg'] se guardase con el usuario para poder bloquear el acceso al formulario.
En principio intenté darle un valor para tener dos tipos de usuarios: Registrado y Administrador, pero no he conseguido que funcione.
También se me ocurrió hacer la variable global, pero no conseguí hacerla funcionar.
La verdad que soy un desastre, se me ocurrió ordenar el código por carpetas para dejarlo bonito y distraerme de este problema que no consigo sacar adelante. Y tarde una hora casi en solucionar la redistribución
<?php

session_start();

$_SESSION['reg'] = false;

//Abro la conexión con la base de datos
include "../bbdd/conexiondb.php";

// Verificar si se envió el formulario
if (isset($_POST['usuario']) && isset($_POST['password'])) {
    
    $usuario = $_POST['usuario'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    //Le pido algo a la base da datos
    $peticion = "
    SELECT * FROM usuarios
    WHERE
    Usuario = '".$_POST['usuario']."'
    AND
    Password = '".$_POST['password']."'
    LIMIT 1
    ";

    $resultado = mysqli_query($enlace,$peticion);

//Devuelvo por pantalla lo que me de
if ($fila = $resultado->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo "Bienvenido " . $fila['Usuario'] . "<br>";
    $_SESSION['usuario'] = $fila['Usuario'];
    $_SESSION['reg'] = true;
    echo "Login Correcto <br>";
    header("Location: ../noticias.php"); // Redirección
}else{
    echo "Login Incorrecto <br>";
    header("Location: ../login.php");
    }
}

//Cierro los recursos abiertos
mysqli_close($enlace);

?>

}

Pero cuando quiero entrar con mi login en el formulario.php, no me deja, me dice que la variable es false:
<?php  

session_start();

if (isset($_SESSION['reg']) && $_SESSION['reg'] === true) {

} else {
    //Si no está logueado, bloquea el acceso y redirecciona
    header("Location: noticias.php");
    exit;
}
?>

Ya intente meterle que la variable $reg fuese global, y funcionaba a duras penas. Llevo tres horas dándole vueltas y no consigo saber porque no funciona.
Quizá sea problema del navbar que le meti:
<nav class="navbar">
    <div class="container">
        <?php session_start();?>
        <?php if (isset($_SESSION['usuario'])) : ?>
            <span>Bienvenido <?php echo $_SESSION['usuario']; ?></span>
            <a href="login/logout.php">Cerrar sesión</a>
            <?php else : ?>
            <span>No has iniciado sesión</span>
            <a href="login.php">Iniciar sesión</a>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </div>
</nav>


Después del include vuelves a poner la sesión en false?? $_SESSION['reg'] = false; no sería al revés?? Sino es así dime donde la pones en true ??

Primero que nada aprende a controlar los valores. Si tienes un problema y estás viendo que la sesión no se mantiene entre páginas, quita el "logout" por asi llamarle. El if y else, de la 2da página, deberían (durante el desarrollo) mostrar los valores de las variables, y asi tu entender por que están llenas con ciertos valores, o vacías. Ahora, por que cambias el valor de sesión a FALSE, sin ninguna validación de por medio ??

Ya borré el $_SESSION['reg']= false que tenía duplicado, después del
if ($fila = $resultado->fetch_assoc()) {     $_SESSION['usuario'] = $fila['Usuario'];     $_SESSION['reg'] = true;     header("Location: ../noticias.php"); // Redirección a index
Pero no entiendo porque pierdo los datos por el camino, si cuando carga la página me dicen que están bien.

Con eso me refería a controlar que valores son los que recibe la 2da página luego del session_start(). Prueba a poner un echo con los valores del session, y muestra si recibes los valores o no. También puedes editar la publicación, y actualizar el código, a ver como esta ahora.

Ya os edité el código, gracias por todo.

Los dos valores que inicias, usuario y reg, con que valor llegan a la 2da pagina después del session_start y antes del if ???

Por favor no generes más trabajo a los otros usuarios vandalizando tu publicación. Por política de SE, cualquier clase de vandalismo será revertido. Si queres saber más sobre cómo eliminar una publicación, considera mirar: ¿Cómo funciona la eliminación de publicaciones? ¿Por qué podría eliminarse una publicación y qué implica? ¿Cuál es el criterio para eliminar.

Respondiendo al título de tu pregunta:
La variable de sesión SI se mantiene mientras tú

inicies la sesión con session_start() y sus mecanismos funcionen y
no re-asignes la variable, ya sea dándole otro valor, llamando a unset() o hagas otra acción que sobre-escriba o destruya el valor.

Viendo tu código, creo que aún te falta desarrollar algunos conceptos importantes. En lugar de ir por los detalles de cada tema o problema que pueda tener tu código, siguiendo la filosofía de enseñarte a pescar en lugar de darte el pescado y pensando en quienes lleguen aquí tratando de resolver sus propios errores en sus scripts, creo que podría funcionar mejor que veas y puedas estudiar un ejemplo funcional.
He preparado tres scripts que tienen las piezas básicas para realizar el típico inicio de sesión, acceso restringido al contenido solo para usuarios que han iniciado sesión y cierre de la misma.
OJO, que lo primero que debes diferenciar aquí, es cuando hablamos de sesión a nivel de usuario y cuando hablamos de sesión a nivel del servidor.
Comencemos por ello, antes de los scripts.

Sesión de PHP, o sesión a nivel del servidor: La sesión a nivel de servidor es una especie de almacen, que nos permite almacenar valores y recuperarlos entre distintas llamadas al servidor. Usualmente se basa en una cookie que tiene un identificador único para cada sesión. Lee la documentación de session_start() y los temas relacionados en ella.
Sesión de usuario: Esta es una construcción donde, a través de nuestra programación, restringimos el acceso al contenido de un sitio solo para usuarios registrados. El inicio de sesión, consiste en la validación de este acceso. La manera más básica (y arcaica) es usuario y contraseña. Hoy por hoy están de moda las passkey. Para hacer esto funcionar, habrá tantas maneras como programadores. Lo que muestro en los scripts a continuación es una manera muy básica, pero tiene la ventaja de tener solo estos primeros bloques sobre los que construir la idea.

Los mecanismos los explicaré después, ahora, el código.
Como he dicho antes, son tres scripts. Si los colocas en una carpeta en un servidor con cualquier versión de php moderna y los nombres de archivo sugerido, debiera funcionar.
contenido.php
<?php
session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION['usuario'])) {
    header("Location: login.php");
    die();
} 
$usuario = htmlspecialchars($_SESSION['usuario']);
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Contenido</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <main>
        <h1>Contenido de la página</h1>  
        <p>Aquí podrás estar solo si has iniciado sesión!</p>
        <foot>Usuario: <strong><? echo($usuario); ?></strong>  <a href="logout.php">cerrar sesión</a></foot>
    </main>
  </body>
</html>

logout.php
<?php
session_start();
unset($_SESSION['usuario']);
header("Location: login.php");
?>

login.php
<?php
session_start();
if (isset($_GET['usuario']) && ($_GET['usuario'] != "")) {
    $_SESSION['usuario'] = $_GET['usuario'];
}    
if (isset($_SESSION['usuario'])) {
    header("Location: contenido.php");
    die();
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Inicio de sesión</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <main>
        <h1>Inicio de sesión</h1>  
        <form method="get">
          <label for="usuario">Usuario</label>
          <input type=text" id="usuario" name="usuario"><br>
          <button>Iniciar sesión</button><br>
        </form>
    </main>
  </body>
</html>

El comportamiento a nivel de usuario tendría que ser:

si tratas de navegar a contenido.php sin antes haber iniciado sesión, no va a mostrar su contenido y te va a redirigir a login.php
si tratas de navegar a login.php con una sesión (de usuario) ya iniciada, te va a redirigir a contenido.php
en login.php introduce un nombre de usuario no vacío, clic en Iniciar sesión y con esto el servidor recordará tu nombre de usuario y te redirigirá a contenido.php, dónde podrás ver el magnífico contenido del sitio, además de tu nombre de usuario en el pie de página, y tendrás un link para cerrar tu sesión.
logout.php cierra la sesión y te redirige a login.php, donde puedes volver a comenzar.

Viendo las cosas desde los ladrillos con los que se ha construido la solución, podrás darte cuenta de los siguientes aspectos::

Dado que nos valemos de información almacenada en la sesión en el servidor, todos los scripts inician llamando a session_start(). Sin esta llamada no tenemos acceso a los valores almacenados (o no) en la sesión.
En esta sesión del servidor, cuando el usuario inicia sesión satisfactoriamente almacenamos una variable usuario. En los scripts, nos basamos en la existencia de esta variable para determinar si un usuario ha iniciado sesión satisfactoriamente o no.
Lo implementamos comprobando si la variable ha sido establecida llamando a isset() con la construcción:
if (isset($_SESSION['usuario']) bla, bla, bla


Lo esencial del cierre de sesión es desestablecer esta variable, para ello llamo a unset().
Cuándo hace falta, redirigimos al usuario a otra página enviando un header Location antes de producir cualquier salida en la página. Si hace falta, interrumpimos la ejecución del resto del script con die()
En contenido, trasladamos el dato del nombre de usuario a una variable corriente, teniendo el cuidado de prepararlo para poder usarlo en la salida con una llamada a htmlspecialchars()

Espero que la explicación resulte suficiente para que el código hable por si solo. Si después de estudiar el código y leer mis explicaciones tienes dudas, deja un comentario.
Después de este ejercicio y el esfuerzo necesario, creo que podrás identificar los errores en tu código, resolverlos y seguir adelante.

Te hice un login super mega hiper básico para que veas como se hace
index.php verifica si hay alguien registrado, sino lo hay, solo le muestra el link del login.
session_start();
// Inicializar $_SESSION['reg'] como false si no está definida
if (!isset($_SESSION['reg'])) {
    $_SESSION['reg'] = false;

    echo '<a href="login.php">LogIn</a>';
}
else{
    echo 'Bienvenido '.$_SESSION['name'];
    echo '<br><a href="logout.php">LogOut</a>';
}

login.php le da un valor a las variables y lo redirige al index
session_start();
$_SESSION['reg'] = true;
$_SESSION['name'] = 'Marcos Quintana';
header("Location: index.php");

logout.php mata la sesión y lo manda al index
if (!isset($_SESSION)){
    session_start();
}
session_destroy();
header("Location: index.php");

Resultado en pantalla

Bienvenido Marcos Quintana
LogOut

Este ejemplo es un bucle pero ejemplifica bien como se debe hacer todo. Ya solo queda meterle bases y todo lo demás y listo. Espero te ayude 

Gracias pero sigo con el mismo error, no consigo acceso al formulario. Me sigue mandando al "index" noticias.php

Es más probé el código en mi aplicación y si hago el logout. Sale y me indica el login, pero si hago ctrl+F5 me vuelve a loguear. Bueno, hasta las 5am tengo tiempo a darle vueltas

Haz un sesión destroy como hago yo, pueda que tengas una sesión de otro sistema por ahí. Una lastima que solo vengan a votar en contra sin siquiera tener el valor y dar la cara del porque el voto, personas inmaduras hay en todos lados

Gracias por todo, al final he conseguido que funcione. Tengo que borrar el código para que no me acusen de plagio cuando lo busquen. Que dios te bendiga con mucha sidra

Me alegra haber ayudado aunque esta respuesta tenga un voto negativo. Suerte !!!
